# Sharing class attributes between threads

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

Is the following code correct? (it initializes an object who launch a thread in its constructor to alter its state).

```
import threading
import time

class Test():

   def __init__(self):

      self.a = False

      def workload():
         self.a = True             

      self.thread = threading.Thread(target = workload)
      self.thread.start()

   def display(self):
      print self.a

test = Test()

while True:
   test.display()
   time.sleep(0.1)
```

It outputs *True* but I have a more complex test case (that cannot be reproduced easily here) where *workload* does far more complex stuff (involving sleeping, retrieving items from a manager Queue) and where the program never outputs *True* - though the value of *self.a* changes within the workload function. Does Python make temporary copies of shared values between main and child threads and "synchronize" periodically or the issue lies elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Both the `__main__` Process and the Thread `def workload` seems to use the same object.
I added `time.sleep(0.1)` before `self.a = True` to give the `__main__` Process a chance to display **False**.
I get the following output:

```
Start __main__
<__main__.Workload object at 0xf7027fac> <function Workload.__init__.<locals>.workload at 0xf7017c44>
False
<__main__.Workload object at 0xf7027fac> <function Workload.__init__.<locals>.workload at 0xf7017c44>
False
True
True
True
EXIT __main__
```